# ActionSheet lags

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I have code for **ActionSheet** and it is a little slow with what it can be connected?

[image]

```
@IBAction func showAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let actionSheetController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
    actionSheetController.addAction(
        UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("Copy", comment: ""), style: .default, handler: { [weak self] _ in
            guard let strongSelf = self else { return }

            UIPasteboard.general.string = strongSelf.displayResultLabel.text

            let alert = UIAlertController(title: NSLocalizedString("Copied to clipboard", comment: ""), message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
            let when = DispatchTime.now() + 0.5
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when){
                alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
            self?.present(alert, animated: true, completion:nil)
        })
    )
    actionSheetController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("Cancel", comment: ""), style: .cancel, handler: nil))

    present(actionSheetController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: it is a little slow  with what it can be connected -- which one present or dismiss

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik which one present

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `animated: true`

```
present(actionSheetController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

to `animated: false` for omit the delay or animation

```
present(actionSheetController, animated: false, completion: nil)
```